# Terraform aws_codebuild_project error: InvalidInputException:

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, aws-codebuild

I am trying to create a standalone AWS CodeBuild with terraform; it will have no source and no artifacts. But when I try to create it as such

```
resource aws_codebuild_project default {

  ...

  source {
    type = "NO_SOURCE"
  }

  artifacts {
    type = "NO_ARTIFACTS"
  }

  ...

}
```

I am getting error: "InvalidInputException: **Invalid artifacts: artifact type NO_ARTIFACTS should have null output name"**

I've tried set `name` and `namespace_type` to null and it seems to have no effect.

I am running terraform v0.12.26 and AWS provider v2.70.0

Any idea what is causing this error and how to fix it?

Comment: Odd. Is the resource definition you've posted definitely the same as what you're actually using? No typos, or other `aws_codebuild_project` blocks elsewhere in your directory that are wrong?

Comment: I tried to replicate with `Terraform v0.12.28` and `aws = "2.70.0"`, but I it works for me. Maybe if you could provide minimal reproducible code that can be just copied and pasted, it would be easier to verify.

Answer (score 1):

I catch this problem too. I fixed it with delete and re apply